# Rename [typetraits] to [type-traits]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The [typetraits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typetraits) tag refers to traits in the [`<type_traits>` C++ header](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

Spelling it with no hyphen neither makes sense from an English language perspective, nor from a C++ domain perspective.

Comment: Agreed that the current name is bad, but looking for domain expertise: should the result be [type_traits] (referring to the header's name) or [type-traits] (referring to the concept of type traits generally)?

Comment: @RyanM I wasn't even aware that tags on SO can have underscores. No other C++ tags follow this style to my knowledge; e.g. it's the `std::unordered_set` class in the header `<unordered_set>`, but the tag is [tag:unordered-set]. Neither the type names nor the header names strictly impose an underscore, so I don't see a reason why [tag:typetraits] would need to.

Comment: The name "type traits" sometimes refers to the design pattern of a type trait in the style of those in `<type_traits>`, but the tag is mostly used in conjunction with literally the traits in `<type_traits>`. It's a bit of a mix.

Comment: *"I wasn't even aware that tags on SO can have underscores."* that's...probably because [they actually can't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298981/165261).  Oops. [type-traits] it is, then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Makes sense, and it's consistent with how we write other multi-word tags. Done.

```
updating post history, 1509 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 1220 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'type-traits' doesn't exist, renaming 'typetraits' to 'type-traits'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [type-traits] and [typetraits] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
20 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
1 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym typetraits -> type-traits was approved!
```

(I think the synonym was actually not created due to the tags differing only by a hyphen)